# Strongly typed dataset - XML Serialization

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset, xml-serialization, strongly-typed-dataset

I have a typed dataset in my project and i need to import data from XML. I managed to import data to Tables collection in my typed dataset, but I need to have access to the data via Annotations - properties named the same as tables in my dataset.

```
this.ConfigDataSet.Reset();
this.ConfigDataSet.ReadXml(FileName,XmlReadMode.ReadSchema);
this.ConfigDataSet.AcceptChanges();
```

Do I have to copy data field by field?

I have something like this:

```
this.ConfigDataSet.Tables["TabName"].Rows.Count //returns 3 
this.ConfigDataSet.TabName.Rows.Count //returns 0
```

I write xml like this:

```
this.ConfigDataSet.AcceptChanges();
this.ConfigDataSet.WriteXml(FileName,XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
```

Comment: have you check your `xml` file, is it writing data in the file ?

Comment: yes, it is. As I said, data is in the new dataset but in just in Table property.

Comment: check the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

WriteXml:

```
                ConfigDataSet.WriteXml(FileName);
```

ReadXml:

```
                    using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
                {
                    ds.ReadXml(FileName);
                    ConfigDataSet.Load(ds.Tables[0].CreateDataReader(), LoadOption.OverwriteChanges, ConfigDataSet.TableName1);
                    ConfigDataSet.Load(ds.Tables[1].CreateDataReader(), LoadOption.OverwriteChanges, ConfigDataSet.TableName2);
                    ConfigDataSet.Load(ds.Tables[2].CreateDataReader(), LoadOption.OverwriteChanges, ConfigDataSet.TableName3);
                    ConfigDataSet.Load(ds.Tables[3].CreateDataReader(), LoadOption.OverwriteChanges, ConfigDataSet.TableName4);
                }
```

It is required to load each table separately, but it is better than load each field row by row.

Regards, Kuba.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DataTable tbl = GetTable();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.Tables.Add(tbl);
        //file path to write xml file
        ds.WriteXml("test.xml");

        DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
        //file path to read xml file
        ds2.ReadXml("test.xml");
    }
    static DataTable GetTable()
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Dosage", typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("Drug", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Patient", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));

        table.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin", "David", DateTime.Now);
        table.Rows.Add(50, "Enebrel", "Sam", DateTime.Now);
        table.Rows.Add(10, "Hydralazine", "Christoff", DateTime.Now);
        table.Rows.Add(21, "Combivent", "Janet", DateTime.Now);
        table.Rows.Add(100, "Dilantin", "Melanie", DateTime.Now);
        return table;
    }
}
```

Check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.writexml.aspx) for `DataSet.WriteXml()` and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.readxml.aspx) for `DataSet.ReadXml()`;

Comment: Thanks for replay. Unfortunately this example shows XML reading that I actually did. These datasets aren't typically strongly typed DataSet - they don't have special property for each table:
[link](http://oi43.tinypic.com/2zpuvrm.jpg)

Comment: Have you checked it out `DataSet.WriteXml();` and `DataSet.ReadXml();` in msdn

Comment: As I understand, I cannot export/import strongly typed using standard methods WriteXML and ReadXML, right?